# Mount a volume within a mounted volume

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount, fstab

I am setting up a new Linux Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2 and wanted to create a few extra volumes, to be mounted without execute permissions.

- `/tmp` for temporary files
- `/var` so that log files and mysql DBs have their own disk
- `/var/www` for websites

Now `/var/www` would be mounted within `/var` I wonder if that is a problem, since also `/var` is a mounted volume, or is a normal thing to do?

Also are `/etc/fstab` volumes mounted from top to bottom, and in that case should I put `/var` first and `/var/www` after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the fstab manual:

```
The order of records in fstab is important because fsck(8), mount(8),
and umount(8) sequentially iterate through fstab doing their thing.
```

So yes, lines in the beginning got processed first, so put /var before /var/www. As to the second question: you can safely mount filesystems within a mounted one, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why you can't do this, really.

Bear in mind that normally, `/` is just `/dev/sda1` or wherever, and you can mount whatever you like under `/`, such as `/home` as a NFS mount.

Remember that you can also change where MySQL stores it's files, so they're not in the default `/var/lib/mysql`, ditto `/var/www`.

Personally, `/var/www` makes a lot less sense to me than `/srv/<sitename>`